# Text doesn't get posted on Twitter

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter

I am trying to implement a functionality to post tweets on twitter in asp.Net and C#. I have got access token, consumer key, callback url etc. I have two buttons "autheticate" and "Send" to authenticate and send tweets respectively.

I am using Twitterizer2 dll for all this. Authenticate and Send buttons' click **do not give any error but also do not post anything on twitter**. Is there anything I need to add or change? Kindly help.

```
protected void btnSendTwitterMsg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OAuthTokens accessToken = new OAuthTokens();
    accessToken.ConsumerKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    accessToken.ConsumerSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    accessToken.AccessToken = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    accessToken.AccessTokenSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    TwitterStatus.Update(accessToken, "Hello World!!");
}

protected void btnAuthenticate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var consumerKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    var consumerSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    var callBackUrl = "my call back url";

    if (Request.QueryString["oauth_token"] == null)
    {
        OAuthTokenResponse RequestToken = OAuthUtility.GetRequestToken(consumerKey, consumerSecret, callBackUrl);
        Response.Redirect("http://twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=" + RequestToken.Token);            
    }
    else
    {
        OAuthTokenResponse RequestToken = OAuthUtility.GetRequestToken(consumerKey, consumerSecret, callBackUrl);
        string oathToken = Request.QueryString["oauth_token"].ToString();
        var accessToken = OAuthUtility.GetAccessToken(consumerKey, consumerSecret, RequestToken.Token, RequestToken.VerificationString);
        this.lblScreenName.Text = "Hello " + accessToken.ScreenName;
    }
}
```

Thanks
Rakesh

Comment: plz format code ptoperly. Hard to read over mobile browser...

Comment: Code formatted. Thanks to Pilgerstorfer Franz

Answer (score 1):

Try Spring.net Twitter, there is an ASP.NET example that does exactly what you want:
http://springframework.net/social-twitter/

Comment: Thanks of the link Paul.. However I rechecked my code and found that TwitterStatus.Update(accessToken, "Hello World!!");
statement returns a TwitterResponse object, which says "unauthorized" in it's resultset property. Now I am trying to get "oauth_token" and "oauth_verifier" variables through querystring but these variables are not being found in callback url (redirected by twitter). I mean these variables are set there through twitter but my application returns them as null. I am trying to find out why is it so. Please help if you guys have any idea.